# Partial derivatives of state function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

we were given following state function:

[image]

and now we need to find:

[image]

How would we proceed to find the expression? I tried to find V:

[image]

Now I took the derivative; I tried doing it but I am not sure if it is correct,

[image]

and in the last row I was not sure, if I should just leave V as is, or substitute it with the state function for V, because that would be a lot more complicated. Any help would really, really be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $(\partial V_m/\partial T)_p(\partial T/\partial p)_{V_m}(\partial p/\partial V_m)_T =-1$

Comment: Thanks for the help, when and how would I use this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$p(T,V_m) = \frac{RT}{V_m-b} - \frac{a}{V_m(V_m-b)}$$

$$T(p,V_m) = \frac{1}{R}\left(p(V_m-b)+\frac{a}{V_m}\right)$$

We will use the cyclic identity

$$\left(\frac{\partial V_m}{\partial T}\right)_p\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial p}\right)_{V_m}\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V_m}\right)_T = -1$$

We first find

\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial p}\right)_{V_m} &= \frac{V_m-b}{R}\\
\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V_m}\right)_{T} &= \frac{a(2V_m-b)}{V_m^2(V_m-b)^2}-\frac{RT}{(V_m-b)^2}\\
&=\frac{a(2V_m-b)}{V_m^2(V_m-b)^2}-\frac{RTV_m^2}{V_m^2(V_m-b)^2}
\end{align*}

Thus, using the cyclic identity,

$$\left(\frac{\partial V_m}{\partial T}\right)_p = -\frac{RV_m^2(V_m-b)^2}{(V_m-b)(2aV_m-ab-RTV_m^2)} = -\frac{RV_m^2(V_m-b)}{(2aV_m-ab-RTV_m^2)}$$

and obviously

$$\alpha = -\frac{RV_m(V_m-b)}{(2aV_m-ab-RTV_m^2)}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, but why doesn't my method work? I get that your response is more elegant, but I don't get why

Comment: Assuming you did no mistakes, the two should be equivalent after some substitutions.

Comment: Ah okay thanks :D gotcha